# upgrade to a new version

Tags: upgrade

I am using ubuntu 10.10 version and want to upgrade to a new version but my update manager said it is not possible what should I do? please help me. I  had tried many times to upgrade it but it always give error about Internet connection.

Comment: This is really an old Version of Ubuntu. Can you please provide the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

The support for Ubuntu 10.10 has ended in 2012. You cannot upgrade to 14.04 from it.

The only solution is a fresh install from a DVD or USB drive.

The error is not about your internet connection. It is the HTTP 404 not found error because the repositories for 10.10 are not online anymore.